# Getting errors after installing & uinstalling flake8 plugins. Errors thrown when doing --help or --version

Tags: python-3.x, pip, flake8

I was playing around with different flake8 plugins today and after uninstalling one of them and installing a new one, `flake8 --version` no longer works for me.

the flake8 packages I had at the time were

`(python3) $ flake8 --version 3.8.4 (flake8-bugbear: 20.11.1, mccabe: 0.6.1, naming: 0.11.1, pycodestyle: 2.6.0, pyflakes: 2.2.0) CPython 3.8.2 on Darwin`

after which I had ran

- `pip uninstalled flake8-bugbear`
- `pip install flake8-docstrings`
- `pip uninstall flake8-docstrings`
- `pip install flake8-comprehensions`

It now breaks with this error on `flake8 --version`

```
(python3) $ flake8 --version
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/dtan/code/python3/bin/flake8", line 8, in <module>
    sys.exit(main())
  File "/Users/dtan/code/python3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/flake8/main/cli.py", line 22, in main
    app.run(argv)
  File "/Users/dtan/code/python3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/flake8/main/application.py", line 363, in run
    self._run(argv)
  File "/Users/dtan/code/python3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/flake8/main/application.py", line 350, in _run
    self.initialize(argv)
  File "/Users/dtan/code/python3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/flake8/main/application.py", line 332, in initialize
    self.parse_configuration_and_cli(
  File "/Users/dtan/code/python3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/flake8/main/application.py", line 182, in parse_configuration_and_cli
    self.options, self.args = aggregator.aggregate_options(
  File "/Users/dtan/code/python3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/flake8/options/aggregator.py", line 45, in aggregate_options
    parsed_config = config_parser.parse()
  File "/Users/dtan/code/python3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/flake8/options/config.py", line 312, in parse
    return self.merge_user_and_local_config()
  File "/Users/dtan/code/python3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/flake8/options/config.py", line 277, in merge_user_and_local_config
    config = self.parse_local_config()
  File "/Users/dtan/code/python3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/flake8/options/config.py", line 240, in parse_local_config
    return self._parse_config(config)
  File "/Users/dtan/code/python3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/flake8/options/config.py", line 217, in _parse_config
    value = method(self.program_name, option_name)
  File "/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/Library/Frameworks/Python3.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/configparser.py", line 828, in getboolean
    return self._get_conv(section, option, self._convert_to_boolean,
  File "/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/Library/Frameworks/Python3.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/configparser.py", line 808, in _get_conv
    return self._get(section, conv, option, raw=raw, vars=vars,
  File "/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/Library/Frameworks/Python3.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/configparser.py", line 803, in _get
    return conv(self.get(section, option, **kwargs))
  File "/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/Library/Frameworks/Python3.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/configparser.py", line 1163, in _convert_to_boolean
    raise ValueError('Not a boolean: %s' % value)
ValueError: Not a boolean: true # Print the source code generating the error/warning in question
```

I've already tried uninstalling & reinstalling flake8 with no luck.  I assume that something is broken on the documentation stuff since doing `flake8 --help` will also throw this error

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems one of the plugins had added a config parser and changed one of [the configuration files](https://flake8.pycqa.org/en/latest/user/configuration.html#configuration-locations). When uninstalled the parser was removed but it left the changes in config file(s).

You need to run through all `flake8` config files and remove config sections for uninstalled plugins.

Comment: Thanks!  I didn't realize `flake8 --version` looked at the project's setup.cfg file I was using.  I had (stupidily) put a # comment at the end of the line and that was causing the errors